# Can't iterate Backbone collection... again

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Seems like every Q&A on this same question has a different reason as to why it doesn't work. I have this simple iterator in my render...

```
    render: function() {
        console.log('MembersView render collection',this.collection);
        //_.each(this.collection.models, function (model){
        this.collection.each(function (model) {
            console.log('MembersView render model',model);
        });
        this.$el.html(template({ "members":this.collection }));
        return this.el;
    },
```

Here is Chrome console showing what is in this.collection. You can see it clearly is a collection...

[image]

And yet I cannot iterate. Console should log 7 member models and it does not. I have no clue what's happening. I'm using `this.collection.on('reset'...` to call the render at the correct time. Can you see what I'm doing wrong. I really, really, really appreciate your help.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Instead of using `console.log`, use `debugger`. Console log actually writes a weird sort of reference, which can *change*. Meaning, the collection may be empty when your code executes, but populated later, in which case the console will update to reflect the populated collection.

Comment: Unbelievable. I switched from calling render on reset event, to using the fetch success callback and it works fine. So have I now learned that BB reset event fires *prior* to the collection being filled? Post this answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Did some more searching and found: `collection.fetch({reset:true})`. Apparently the collection only does partial fetches as needed. If you add the option `{reset:true}`, it forces a full collection load/reset. I haven't tried this yet, but it may be part of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a attribute `models` in collection, you can use:

```
for(var i=0; i<this.collection.length; ++i){
    console.log('MembersView render model',this.collection.models[i]);
}
```